# Using the xpathResult of the document.evaluate() as a contextNode does not work

Tags: javascript

While using document.evaluate I try to use xpathResult again as a contextNode similar to the example attached and without success, where was I wrong?

```js
const getAllLiButton = document.querySelector("#get-all-li");
const getTitleAndTextButton = document.querySelector("#get-title-text");

getAllLiButton.addEventListener("click", getAllLi);
getTitleAndTextButton.addEventListener("click", getTitleAndText);

function getAllLi() {
  var records = [];

  let topLevelResults = document.evaluate("/html/body/ul/li", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

  var levelResult = topLevelResults.iterateNext();
  while (levelResult) {
    records.push(levelResult);
    
    levelResult = topLevelResults.iterateNext();
  }

  console.log(records);
}

function getTitleAndText() {
  let topLevelResults = document.evaluate("/html/body/ul/li", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

  var levelResult = topLevelResults.iterateNext();

  let titleText = document.evaluate("/h3", levelResult, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
  console.log(titleText);

  let textBox = document.evaluate("/span", levelResult, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
  console.log(textBox);
}
```

```html
<button id="get-all-li">Get all li (works)</button>
<button id="get-title-text">Get single Title & Text (not works)</button>

<ul>
  <li><h3>Title #1</h3><span>some text</span></li>
  <li><h3>Title #2</h3><span>some text</span></li>
  <li><h3>Title #3</h3><span>some text</span></li>
  <li><h3>Title #4</h3><span>some text</span></li>
  <li><h3>Title #5</h3><span>some text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reported in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate):

```
document.evaluate(".//h3", levelResult, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null)
```

The **.//h3** xpathExpression is important to indicate that the query should start from the context node (levelResult).

```js
const getAllLiButton = document.querySelector("#get-all-li");
const getTitleAndTextButton = document.querySelector("#get-title-text");

getAllLiButton.addEventListener("click", getAllLi);
getTitleAndTextButton.addEventListener("click", getTitleAndText);

function getAllLi() {
    var records = [];

    let topLevelResults = document.evaluate("/html/body/ul/li", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

    var levelResult = topLevelResults.iterateNext();
    while (levelResult) {
        records.push(levelResult);

        levelResult = topLevelResults.iterateNext();
    }

    console.log(records);
}

function getTitleAndText() {
    let topLevelResults = document.evaluate("/html/body/ul/li", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

    var levelResult = topLevelResults.iterateNext();

    let titleText = document.evaluate(".//h3", levelResult, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
    titleText = titleText.iterateNext();
    console.log(titleText.textContent);

    let textBox = document.evaluate(".//span", levelResult, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
    textBox = textBox.iterateNext();
    console.log(textBox.textContent);
}
```

```html
<button id="get-all-li">Get all li (works)</button>
<button id="get-title-text">Get single Title & Text (not works)</button>

<ul>
    <li><h3>Title #1</h3><span>some text</span></li>
    <li><h3>Title #2</h3><span>some text</span></li>
    <li><h3>Title #3</h3><span>some text</span></li>
    <li><h3>Title #4</h3><span>some text</span></li>
    <li><h3>Title #5</h3><span>some text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Amazing! Although I went through the document.evaluate documentation again and again I did not notice this directive, wow thank you very much!