# How to use XPath in a newly opened window?

Tags: javascript, xpath

With the code below (intended for a bookmarklet), I am trying to open a new window, look for certain span-elements, and click each of them. However, I cannot access the code of the new window through XPath.

- Inserting the code (copy & paste) of the `clickElem function` directly in the new tab works fine
- CORS is not a problem since it's the same domain/subdomain/protocol
- I've been also following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310680/how-can-i-run-a-script-in-another-newly-opened-tab).

**JavaScript:**

```js
const w = window.open('https://example.com', 'Example', 'width=500, height=500');
w.clickElem = () => {
    const xpath = '//span[text()="Click here"]';
    const selectedNodeElements = w.document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    let currentNode = selectedNodeElements.iterateNext();
    while (currentNode) {
        currentNode.click();
        currentNode = selectedNodeElements.iterateNext();
    }
}
setTimeout(w.clickElem, 8000);
```

When I try to access the text via `currentNode.textContent` I receive following error:

`"Error in protected function: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')"`

Grateful for every hint!

Comment: Cors will be an issue if you use a different protocol such as https instead of http or a different subdomain such as www. Also the ports have to be the same.

Comment: In my case, it's the same domain, subdomain and protocol

Comment: Just use query selector on the window document then to see if you can access the dom.

Comment: This is working fine, I can access an element in the newly opened window through query selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my own mistake after going through my code on and on and coming across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678056/using-the-xpathresult-of-the-document-evaluate-as-a-contextnode-does-not-work). The `.iterateNext()` didn't work because the context node was wrongly set to `document`. Instead, it should be `w.document` to reference the newly opened window.

```js
const selectedNodeElements = w.document.evaluate(xpath, w.document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are already inside your tab? I'm thinking about something you need to get the active tab like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718256/how-do-you-use-chrome-tabs-getcurrent-to-get-the-page-object-in-a-chrome-extensi)?

Comment: This looks like a comment rather than a direct answer to the question. You can consider adding this as a comment next time instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: This looks like a comment rather than a direct answer to the question. You can consider adding this as a comment next time instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I also believe a reference to the window is missing but I cannot figure out where. Trying to invoke an alert in the newly opened tab e.g. is functioning.

Unfortunately, I cannot use the Chrome Extension API since it has to run as a bookmarklet and not as an extension.